# Host network interface and docker internal network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops

How would I express having a container connected to the host machine and to a internal network? What I want to do is connect a network interface from the host inside a container and have information flow into an internal docker-compose network and vice versa back to the host

`external  |                   internal network                   | external
Host eth0 -> [eth0 Container] -> [Container] -> [Container eth0] -> Host eth0`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to `docker create network` and attach all the containers on that network. Then you can expose the ports for the container that needs to be externally available and bind them to the ports on the host.

Depending on that if you're using `docker run`, `docker compose`, or `dockerfiles` you can do the above in slightly different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want my container to have access to the host network interface and to internal docker interface, I think I might have found a solution http://stevemcgrath.io/2017/07/docker-containers--network-sniffing/

Comment: Seems like it would work, however is there a particular reason you don't just use the docker bridge network, instead of creating a separate bridge and then assigning docker to it? I mean it still works, it just adds a layer of complexity, and keeping it simple makes it simple to maintain.

Comment: Because in the bridge network I don't have access to the host's network interface, the bridge is local to the internal set of containers